# In XAML how to copy a resource to a different tag name dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My question is almost identical to this one:

[How to assign WPF resources to other resource tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036563/how-to-assign-wpf-resources-to-other-resource-tags)

except that question works only for static resources.  I want to know how to do it with dynamic resources.  In detail:

I'm using resources as 'class variables' to control the color of an object.  So I have this:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomScrollBarStyle" TargetType="{x:Key ScrollBar}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightColor" Color="Blue"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Template".../>
 </Style>
```

And I can customize the color whenever I use a scrollbar:

```
<ScrollBar>
    <ScrollBar.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightColor" Color="Yellow">/
    </ScrollBar.Resources>
</ScrollBar>
```

This works really well, provided I always reference HighlightColor with {DynamicResource}.  But I don't know how to bring it one level higher.  For example I have a combo box that also has it's own color style.  I want to use this color on the scrollbars also:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxColor" Color="Black"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    ...
    <ControlTemplate>
        <ScrollBar>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightColor" ???? use ComboBoxColor/>
        </ScrollBar>
    </ControlTemplate>
    ...
</Style>
```

I've tried using a binding, but it gives an exception that a binding source can't be a DynamicResource.  If I bind to the color as a StaticResource it just uses the default color.  I've also tried creating a DynamicResource directly but it complains that only works for a dependency property and can't be inserted directly into a resource dictionary.

So how can I dynamically create a new resource from an existing one?

Thanks.

**Update**
It looks like there's no way to do this.  So I've decided to just use attached properties instead.  They work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you create a Color resource like this

```
<Color x:Key="KeyName">#112233</Color>
```

and set it as value for your Brushes.

In the code you provided, you are trying to set a Property of Color type with a SolidColorBrush value.

Comment: That's what I've done but it only works because of the nature of Color and Brush.  I'd really like to know if there's a way to do this in general- use resources as properties that inherit so you don't have to subclass anything.

Comment: Inheritance is possible with Style(BasedOn Property) but not with Brushes as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Add the resource to your top Page.Resource (or Control.Resource). Then, access it using StaticResource.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightColor" Color="Yellow">/
</Page.Resources>

<TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource HighlightColor}"/>
```

Comment: This won't work.  I want the scrollbar color to inherit the combobox color.  So anyone using the combo box anywhere else can override the color and it will automatically show up in the scroll bars. And only for those scroll bars.  Other ones will use whatever colors they are overridden with.

Comment: Ah, then what you need is to create a ViewModel that stores the color for you. You can then override it with whatever color you want, including at runtime, and then retrieve it using bindings.

Comment: I know that works but it would be great if there was a way to do this in pure XAML.  Resources work so well as local variables if only you can override them.

Comment: What would work is some sort of copy constructor for resources.  For example (in <Resources>): <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightColor" Value="{DynamicResources ComboboxColor}"/>  Value isn't a real property so this doesn't work.